# Bootstrap collapsed fixed div jumpy on load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsed div that is triggered by a link. I did not want the collapsed div to show up just below, but rather on top of the page. I gave the div position:fixed. When I trigger the collapsed div, it first opens in the default position (just below my trigger button) but then jumps to the top where I'd like it to be. This happens in a split second, but it still bothers me because it isn't smooth. How can the transition happen smoother?

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#refine">Trigger</a>
<div class="collapse" id="refine" style="position:fixed; top:100px; z-index:10000;">...</div>
```

Comment: It would be better to show it live, than giving the code. Can you reproduce the same thing in a http://jsbin.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript which handles the collapse adds "position:relative" to the element while it animates it. You could try to make it "important" in css, like this:

```
position:fixed !important;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had position:absolute set on #refine.collapsing and on #refine.collapse.in. Changed both to fixed and voila!